# Apache Pig store delimiters

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I'm using Pig Latin to store values from an alias into the HDFS. The alias contains a semicolon in one of its fields.

```
dump A;
(Richard &amp; John, 1993)
(Albert, 1994)
```

A table that shows the data in the HDFS, but the semicolon makes John go to the next column.

```
    |  Name        | Year |
    |--------------|------|
    | Richard &amp | John |
    | Albert       | 1994 |
```

Trying to use store like this is also not working as expected:

```
STORE A INTO '/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/names' using PigStorage('\t');
```

but even when telling PigStore to use tab as delimiter the semicolon breaks the table data. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I just locally create a file suppose **a.txt** and copy your data into this file.

```
(Richard &amp; John, 1993)
(Albert, 1994)
```

Now I see that your data is not in tab delimiter form and that's why it split after semicolon part.So to solve this problem i just right a query like this

```
data = load '/home/hduser/Desktop/a.txt' using PigStorage(',');
dump data;
```

and my output result is this

```
((Richard &amp; John, 1993))
((Albert, 1994))
```

I split it using this

> **,**

because your data looks like this delimiter.

> Note: I run it my local file system.So to run it locally you must start your pig using this command `pig -x local` and give your relevant path.

Comment: Changing the delimiter in the PigStorage function didn't work. It seems that the delimiter that I was using in the create table was the one that apache pig was looking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was a bug in the create table.

```
create table test.names
(
name varchar(40),
year varchar(40)
)
row format delimited fields terminated by '\073'
lines terminated by '\n';
```

The delimiter I used was \073 (semicolon), so **changing the PigStorage delimiter had no effect**.

I'm using \072 (double colon) and it is now working. I think any other delimiter would work as long as it is not a common or possible character in the input data.